# IIS6, NETWORK SERVICE and IIS_WPG

Tags: security, iis

Is it correct that IIS6, by default, runs under the NetworkService account (NETWORK SERVICE)?  and that NetWorkService is a member of the IIS_WPG group?

Reference:  [Microsoft TechNet page on IIS6 and security identities and groups](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3648346f-e4f5-474b-86c7-5a86e85fa1ff.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, yes, that is correct.  You even reference the appropriate docs.